# In a PostgreSQL query plan, what is the difference between Materialize and Hash?

Tags: postgresql, explain, sql-execution-plan

Here's [an example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/using-explain.html) of a query plan with Materialize:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=4.65..49.46 rows=33 width=488)
   Join Filter: (t1.hundred < t2.hundred)
   ->  ... (outer)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..8.51 rows=10 width=244)
         ->  ... (inner)
```

And here's an example of a query plan with Hash:

```
Hash Join  (cost=230.47..713.98 rows=101 width=488)
   Hash Cond: (t2.unique2 = t1.unique2)
   ->  ... (outer)
   ->  Hash  (cost=229.20..229.20 rows=101 width=244)
         ->  ... (inner)
```

In the second example the results of the inner query are loaded into a hash table and for each of the outer rows the Hash Join will do a hash table lookup.

In the first example the results of the inner are *also* loaded into memory (that's what Materialize means, isn't it?), and for each outer row the Nested Loop Join also has to do a lookup for the correct row in the materialized data. What kind of data structure does it use for that? (Clearly not a hash table.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL explain plan: what is Materialize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029841/sql-explain-plan-what-is-materialize)

Comment: Check the sources: `postgres-9.5/src/backend/executor/nodeMaterial.c`

Comment: It appears the materialised nodes use the ordinary tuple store, while the hashjoin needs to allocate+manage additional memory to store the complete hash machinery+state. (Just compare the file sizes of the sources ...)

Comment: @joop Indeed, looking at the source answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After consulting [the source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_5_3/src/backend/executor/nodeMaterial.c) I see that Materialize is basically just a contiguous cache of rows (a tuplestore) that is constantly rewound and iterated again for each of the outer rows.